# com.sun.jdi.Invocation Exception when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

So I wanted to ask this on StackOverflow but I was pointed here,
I am doing some CS homework for college in Eclipse.
I am having issues viewing my data structure when debugging my custom class.
When I try to expand my class in the variables table under this,
All I can see is : 
Error   Exception occurred: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method..

My class is :
A Hexboard class the extends from AbstractCollection.

I did some research on this and everyone seems to talk about overriding the toString method. No matter what I put in the return for toString, I still get the same error.

I also noticed that when working on the exact same files (shared thru git) that on school computers I do not have this issue and can see my data structure clearly.

Does anyone know why my home computer's eclipse cant properly display this?
Debating reinstalling eclipse. Its really frustrating not being able to see my variables while debugging.

Thanks for your help .

[Heres what this looks like in the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjcmQ.png)

Update I Installed IntelliJ and had the same issue, but was called 
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.AssertionError' exception.

I did some googling here and I found that Inside IntelliJ I can right click under the variables and choose "customize data views" then untoggle "Alternate view for Collection Classes".
This allows me to see my HB variables now.

However I can not find the same kind of option for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

WOW,
Okay i figured it out!

I right clicked somewhere near the variable window, but not quite (cant seem to repeat this), and gotmyself into some preferences where there was a tab called "logical Structures"
there was code here about
Eclipse Collection(java.util.Collection)  return toArray();

I used this info to google

Eclipse Collection(java.util.Collection) "Logical Structures" return

finding this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038169/disable-logical-structure-display-in-variables-view

which i used to add a class "HexBoard" and i put return "test";

and now my debugg variable window properly displays my hexboard.....

I have no idea, but it works.
[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbr4T.png)